# How to create Tap event on Long Tap gesture on UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I have added Long Tap gesture on `UIWebView`. But I want `UIWebView` to process a standard Tap event before my Long Tap will be recognized. (Two gestures should be processed on Long Tap - a simple Tap and my Long Tap). How to do this?

I think it's required to send Tap event to `UIWebView` on `TouchBegin`. Is it correct?

Comment: I want to work them together but UIWebView doesn't process single tap on long tap.

Comment: SingleTapGestureRecognizer and DoubleTapGestureRecognizer don't work on UIWebView at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UILongPressGestureRecognizer* gesture = [[[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleLongPress:)] autorelease];
    gesture.delegate = self;
    [myWebView addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer this section UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

you found this is called when 2 gesture simultaneous work.

`gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:`

Comment: Thanks! But I have added this method with `return true;` and only long tap still works. What I should do else?

Comment: please check in this method single touch event recognize their or not. write `NSLog();` statement in above method.

Comment: It doesn't run on any tap (long tap and signle tap). I have used: `- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer` and activated `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` protocol.

Comment: you assign delegate to your class.

Comment: But how to do it on this case? UIWebView.gestures contains only my LongTap gesture.